# EHCache and DropWizard: Returning no response

Tags: jersey, ehcache, dropwizard

I have successfully integrated SimplePageCachingFilter with DropWizard.

However, there is one thing standing in my way. Whenever an exception in my application is thrown, instead of being routed to my ExceptionMapper I get "Response contains no data" in my API Browser. I also happen to see this pass by in the log. 
`WARN  [2015-02-12 04:06:21,768] net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.GenericResponseWrapper: Discarding message because this method is deprecated.`

Traditionally my ExceptionMapper returns the appropriate Json Responses.

Has anyone else seen anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attaching a debugger to DropWizard (per @CAB's advice) I discovered that the CachingFilter does not write out a response unless the status code is 200.

I extended CachingFilter and overrode the `doFilter` method and ignored the status check. This appears to have solved my problem.

```
@Override
protected void doFilter(final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws Exception {
    if (response.isCommitted()) {
        throw new AlreadyCommittedException("Response already committed before doing buildPage.");
    }
    logRequestHeaders(request);
    PageInfo pageInfo = buildPageInfo(request, response, chain);

    writeResponse(request, response, pageInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put a breakpoint in http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server/1.18.1/com/sun/jersey/server/impl/application/WebApplicationImpl.java#WebApplicationImpl on line 1472 then trigger your error.

That's throwing an exception, and the mapping of the exception to the exception mapper happens in the catch a little deeper in the stack. Probably in ContainerResponse.mapException

Hopefully this will give you enough insight into why it's not being called.

FYI. I got to that code by putting a breakpoint in a exception mapper that was being fired, and looking at the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for the help, after debugging further I discovered a check in the default CachingFilter that prevented the response from being written out. Enjoy the bounty! :)